# Views Jump menu with taxonomy url and custom url

Tags: views

I have problem with jump menu and contextual filters.
My idea is this:

I have taxonomys (a,b,c) URL: **example.com/a** (this works fine with contex. filters)

Then: example.com/a/**hello**

This **hello** is my menu-url (I make it my own)

When I select **a** in this jump menu and click menu-link **hello** , this jump-menu **a** need to be activated. Default is in this jump-menu is **-Any-**

Comment: Is the jump-menu custom code or an exposed filter?

Comment: @PatrickSchefferc check below

Comment: And its not custom code

Answer (score 0):

Here is examples:

First
[image]

And then
[image]